Error authentication AWS EC2 Jenkins server connect to Docker server
I just create my Jenkins server in AWS ec2 instance, and created another server to DOCKER, into the docker server I will run commands from Jenkins server using ssh.
I did the configuration into jenkins using the plugin ssh2 easy and ssh server.

And next I execute a shell command in my job into Jenkins, the command that I execute is for testing if jenkins can access to the server of docker and create a file.

After this configurations and setting the authorized keys for ssh in the docker server (Important: I can connect to the server when I use ssh using sudo su jenkins in the machine directly)
After I execute the Job I got this error:
create ssh session failed with ip=[x.x.x.x],port=[22],username=[ubuntu],password=[*******]
java.io.IOException: Password authentication failed.
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:404)
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPassword(Connection.java:340)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.JenkinsSshClient.getConnection(JenkinsSshClient.java:41)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.JenkinsSshClient.executeCommand(JenkinsSshClient.java:56)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.DefaultSshClient.executeShell(DefaultSshClient.java:168)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.GsshShellBuilder.perform(GsshShellBuilder.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:527)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1833)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage.
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:374)
    ... 14 more
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.io.IOException: Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage.
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:374)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Password authentication failed.
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:404)
    at PluginClassLoader for trilead-api//com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPassword(Connection.java:340)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.JenkinsSshClient.getConnection(JenkinsSshClient.java:41)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.JenkinsSshClient.executeCommand(JenkinsSshClient.java:56)
Caused: jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.GsshPluginException: [GSSH - SFTP]  Exception Password authentication failed.
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.JenkinsSshClient.executeCommand(JenkinsSshClient.java:62)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.client.DefaultSshClient.executeShell(DefaultSshClient.java:168)
    at PluginClassLoader for ssh2easy//jenkins.plugins.ssh2easy.gssh.GsshShellBuilder.perform(GsshShellBuilder.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:527)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1833)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Build step 'Remote Shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

These are the steps to connect the ssh from jenkins to docker server.
Jenkins Server:

sudo su jenkins
ssh-keygen -> empty passphrase
ssh-copy-id ubuntu@x.x.x.x

put the password of docker server



Docker server:

sudo su
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server


systemctl restart ssh or sshd (depending which works)

After the job executes and got the error I dont see any file into docker server
